# Android Drawable XML Code For Text Select Handle

Tags: android, xml, android-theme

I am trying to find the XML code to create a TextSelectHandle. I created three xml files in my drawable folder text_select_handle_middle, text_select_handle_left, and text_select_handle_right. I also added those files to my Style.xml file.

I haven't found any code online that shows how to create the new round text select handlers for android 6.0 marshmallow. Changing the color of the text select handle is my primary reason for wanting to do this.

I also saw a post that linked this website [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) but it didn't have anything on the new round text select handlers.

[image: textSelectHandleImage]

**Style.xml**

```
<item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In values\styles.xml you should change

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/md_red_100</item>
```

for the color you want, so you do not have to redraw text select handler